# Memory allocated within "if" statement, deallocated upon exit

Tags: c++

I'm entering an "if" statement and deleting a dynamically allocated node in a linked list, then reallocating it. The problem is that as soon as I exit the statement, the memory just disappears. Here is the relevant code:

```
if (!headByName)                    //if the node is empty,
    {
        delete headByName;          //deallocate the memory that it has been given, and
        Node headByName(winery);    //reallocate it with the information contained within
                                    //"winery" copied into it 
        return;                     //looking at memory, everything works at this point
    }                               // <- this point right here is where the information goes "poof" and disappears
```

Here is the constructor for Node:

```
List::Node::Node(const Winery& winery) :
item(winery.getName(), winery.getLocation(), winery.getAcres(), winery.getRating()),
nextByName(nullptr),
nextByRating(nullptr)
{

}
```

When I step through with the debugger, everything copies into headByName just fine until I leave the "if" statement. Once I leave, it becomes a null pointer. This also happens when I remove `return` and instead move on to the `else` section. As soon as I leave the `if` area, the memory just goes away.

Comment: `Node headByName(winery)` defines a new auto variable that's only valid within that scope, it's not the same as the `headByName` that is defined outside the scope.

Comment: You are *not* reallocating your `Node`, you are creating a local `Node` which is destroyed when the function exits. You need: `headByName = new Node(winery);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reallocating anything inside your `if` statement. You are declaring a completely independent local variable with the same name `headByName`. That local variable gets destroyed at the end of the block just like any other local variable would.

Stop trying to declare a local variable. If you want to *reallocate* your node, you should do something like

```
headByName = new Node(winery);
```

You said it was a linked list, so you also probably have to properly link it into the list somehow, but that is something you will have to do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is created within the if scope, and thus is deleted at the end of the scope.
In the same fashion than

```
void foo()
{
   int b;
   while ()
   {
    int a;
   }
}
```

b is accesible within the foo() scope, a is accesible within the while's foo scope, and none of them are accesible outside of foo().